# MySQL query: How to calculate the average of values in a row?

Tags: mysql

The AVG() function calculates column-means but how can I retrieve the mean of several values in the same row like so:

```
SELECT MEAN(A.a, A.b, ... , A.n) FROM A;
```

EDIT: sure, as cherouvim suggests I can do:

```
SELECT MEAN(A.a + A.b + ... + A.n) / n FROM A;
```

but I'm trying to find out if there's a leaner way.

Comment: Rich B: I have my personal way how I want to ask questions, you don't need to change my headings systematically!

Comment: If you have columns in the arrangement you describe, it's a red flag that this table is not normalized properly.  They should be rows in a child table.

Comment: @Bill: maybe a smell but I don't think it is the case here. I have single questionnaire item results in a data row which corresponds with one user and one measurement.

Comment: Okay, fair enough.  A smell is not a 100% indicator of a problem.

Comment: @BillKarwin couple of years later: it was a smell! ;)

Comment: meaning it was a problem, or not a problem?

Comment: @BillKarwin meaning, your olfactory sense was correct! we later concluded that the de-normalized solution wasn't good.

Comment: Aha!  Very good, yes, repeating groups of columns violates 1st Normal Form, and it has many practical disadvantages and you discovered.  In my book "SQL Antipatterns", I wrote about this type of denormalization.  I titled the chapter "Metadata Tribbles" because the columns tend to multiply out of control.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
select (A.a + A.b) / 2 from A;
```

Comment: well, I need it more generic, meaning for x vars.

Comment: Surely you'll always know the number or columns for a given table?

Comment: @tharkun: does this mean that you'll be selecting X columns and you don't know X? what are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: sure I can count how many columns I'm selecting and use that count for the division... with my question I'm just trying to find out, if there's a function for that...

Comment: I doubt there would be a function for that. As it is , it's not difficult to achieve. The harder part is coming up with a scenario where it can be used :)

Comment: I can think of many uses. For example, you are tracking 'skills' for a user and want to get the average skill in all categories, or you want to get the center of a set of coordinates. I'm sure that adding and dividing works, however it's not nearly as readable. In a large formula or computation, it can easily cause confusion. It could also lead to errors if someone decides to average a large number of columns and miscounts how many columns exist. MySQL has a 'LEAST' and 'GREATEST' for grabbing the minimum or maximum of a value set. It seems reasonable to me they can do the same thing here.

Answer (score 1):

I stumbled upon a similar situation. This came useful: http://tech-blog.borychowski.com/index.php/2009/02/mysql/average-value-in-a-row/

From the page:

When we do:

```
SELECT *, (V.rank_0 + V.rank_1 + V.rank_2) / 3
AS row_avg FROM voting V
```

we only receive correct averages for the rows where all values are not NULL. But when I have e.g. 3, NULL, 4 I’d like to get 3.5 as a return. That’s the moment when function COALESCE() comes handy.

What does COALESCE () do? From MySQL manual we have:

Returns the first non-NULL value in the list, or NULL if there are no non-NULL values.

```
mysql> SELECT COALESCE(NULL,1);
-> 1
mysql> SELECT COALESCE(NULL,NULL,NULL);
-> NULL
```

And these information will help us to build another SELECT statement:

```
SELECT *,

#first part
(COALESCE(V.rank_0, 0)
+ COALESCE(V.rank_1, 0)
+ COALESCE(V.rank_2, 0))
/

#second part
(3 -
(COALESCE(V.rank_0 - V.rank_0, 1)
+ COALESCE(V.rank_1 - V.rank_1, 1)
+ COALESCE(V.rank_2 - V.rank_2, 1))
) AS row_avg FROM voting V
```

Answer (score 0):

If no one else finds a better solution, you could always just add them together, then divide by the number of columns you added.

Answer (score 0):

Not pretty, but it works.

Not specifically MySql, but the idea should be easy enough to translate over.

```
CREATE TABLE A (id int identity(1,1), C1 int, C2 int, C3 int)
GO

INSERT INTO A VALUES (1,1,1)
INSERT INTO A VALUES (2,2,2)
INSERT INTO A VALUES (3,3,3)
INSERT INTO A VALUES (1,2,3)
INSERT INTO A VALUES (4,5,6)
GO

CREATE VIEW A_Values
AS
SELECT ID, AVG(Val) AS Average 
FROM
(
    SELECT ID, C1 AS Val FROM A
    UNION ALL
    SELECT ID, C2 AS Val FROM A
    UNION ALL
    SELECT ID, C3 AS Val FROM A
) Q
GROUP BY ID
GO


SELECT * FROM A_Values
GO
```

Comment: interesting but not mysql and not leaner ;)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with the MySQL syntax, but what about dumping the row data into a temporary table as multiple rows with a single column, and then using the AVG() function to obtain your result?